# Fill two different object into a single ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview

There are two objects:

```
public class Restaurant {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int type;
    public double duration;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public boolean isStar;
    public int contact;
}

public class Spot {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int type;
    public double duration;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public boolean isStar;
}
```

And I have two array List of each object , and I would like to fill it into the ListView, notice that the only difference between them is Restaurant has contact field. And the adapter is like this

```
public class ResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Restaurant> {

public ResultAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Restaurant> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v =  vi.inflate(R.layout.result_row, null);
    }

    Restaurant p = (Restaurant) getItem(position);

    if (p != null) {
        TextView duration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
        TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.type);
        TextView contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact);

        nameView.setText(p.name);
        addressView.setText(p.address);
        typeView.setText(p.type == 1 ? "Chinese Cuisine" : "Western Cuisine");
        contactView.setText(""+p.contact);
    }

    return v;

}

}
```

The problem is how can I create the adapter in this case, as the adapter is suppose provide one data type?  Do I need to redesign the structure / just create a new Result object?

Update

```
public class Restaurant extends Spot{
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int type;
    public double duration;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public boolean isStar;
    public int contact;

    public Restaurant(String _name, String _address, int _type, double _duration, double _lat, double _lng, boolean _isStar, int _contact) {
        name = _name;
        address = _address;
        type = _type;
        duration = _duration;
        lat = _lat;
        lng = _lng;
        isStar = _isStar;
        contact = _contact;
    }

}
```

Sorry for being weak in OO, how can I change the constructor?

Comment: You have all your fields public and you did not have constructor for Spot. Why do you think you will need one for Restaurant ? You create your spot like this : `Spot s = new Spot();` then assign all fields. Use the same approach for your derived `Restaurant`, no explicit constructor needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an android question.

Just make your `Restaurant` a subtype of `Spot` and have single `List<Spot>` and single adapter managing that list. You will be able to keep `Restaurant` objects there as well, since they are `Spot`s :

```
public class Spot {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int type;
    public double duration;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public boolean isStar;
}

public class Restaurant extends Spot {
    /* the rest is inherited */
    public int contact;
}
```

Your adapter will be

```
//it can hold Both Spot & Restaurant now as well.
public class ResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Spot> {
```

in your `getView()` :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // .. inflate View

    Spot s = (Spot) getItem(position);

    // .. use fields from Spot that are common to fill list view item

    // add info specific to restaurants
    if (s instanceof Restaurant) {
        // fill in extra contact info:
        contactView.setText(((Restauarant) s).contact);
    }

    return v;

}
```

Comment: you ask how to create an adapter ?

Comment: see my update. Basically you just replace `<Restaurant>` with `<Spot>` and you can insert `Restaurant` objects into list/adapter as well.

Comment: @user782104 please see my comment to your question. Let me know if it is still unclear

Comment: Thanks, it seems I need super(_name, _address, _type, _duration, _lat, _lng, _isStar) for constructor , thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need just create a collection of pairs ; each pair will contain two objects  - Restaurant and Spot.

```
List<Pair<Restaurant, Spot>> objects = new ArrayList<Pair<Restaurant, Spot>>();
```

In getView method you will be able to get a pair on special position

```
Pair<Restaurant, Spot> pair = objects.get(position);
Restaurant myRestaurant = pair.first;
Spot mySpot = pair.second;
```

This is not the only solution, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you can do. First, as your `Restaurant` object is almost the same than your `Spot` object, you can extend on from the other like so:

```
public class Spot {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public int type;
    public double duration;
    public double lat;
    public double lng;
    public boolean isStar;

    public Spot(String _name, String _address, int _type, double _duration, double _lat, double _lng, boolean _isStar) {
        name = _name;
        address = _address;
        type = _type;
        duration = _duration;
        lat = _lat;
        lng = _lng;
        isStar = _isStar;
    }
}

public class Restaurant extends Spot {
    public int contact;

    public Restaurant(String _name, String _address, int _type, double _duration, double _lat, double _lng, boolean _isStar, int _contact) {
        super(_name, _address, _type, _duration, _lat, _lng, _isStar);
        contact = _contact;
    }
}
```

Then, for your adapter, you can create one that uses `Object` as all created objects are implicitly extended from `Object` class. After that, you simply have to check the type of each object like so:

```
public class ResultAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

public ResultAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Object> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v =  vi.inflate(R.layout.result_row, null);
    }


    TextView duration = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.duration);
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView address = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.address);
    TextView type = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.type);
    TextView contact = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.contact);

    Spot spot = null;
    Restaurant restaurant = null;
    Object object = getItem(postion);
    if (object.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Restaurant.class) {
        restaurant = object;
    }
    if (object.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Spot.class) {
        spot = object;
    }

    if (spot != null) {
        nameView.setText(spot.name);
        addressView.setText(spot.address);
        typeView.setText(spot.type == 1 ? "Chinese Cuisine" : "Western Cuisine");    
    }
    if (restaurant != null) {
        contactView.setText(""+restaurant.contact);
    }

    return v;

}
```

Comment: @user782104 I updated the code according to your edited question.